# dynamically implementing bold functionality on image button in android like MS word

Tags: android

I have a image button and I want to implement bold and italic functionality just like it is done in MS word, You press bold icon and then the text you write is turned bold automatically.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use html code to do that:

**Bold example, (put word "world" on bold effect)**

```
ImageButton.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hello" + "<b>" + "world" + "</b>"));
```

**Italic example, (put word "world" on italic effect)**

```
ImageButton.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hello" + "<i>" + "world" + "</i>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of methods. First, there is the `Html.from` method already mentiond, then there is `SpannableString`:

```
SpannableString span = new SpannableString("Text here");
span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 5, span.length(), 0);
myTextView.setText(span);
```

This will make the "here" bold and leave "Text" regular.